# Remove Matplotlib Toolbar from the Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing a graph in python using Matplotlib library.
I want to remove the whole toolbar from the graph.
which look like this.

[image: Toolbar menu]

i have been trying alot but not able to figure out the way to do it.
kindly direct me to the File/code and suggest me the modifications to be carried out.

Comment: I don't think you can. You might have to embed it in your own [custom user interface](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/).

Comment: @WesleyBaugh It can be done using `rcParams`.  Making your own interface _is_ a solution, but it is way overkill.

Comment: @tcaswell Cool, thanks. Tried some to search for it but the documentation for [`show()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) didn't give any hints on where to look (`rcParams`). Good to know!

Comment: The place to look to see the logic is in the `FigureManager` sub-class in `backend_*.py` where the gui window is built.  `show` just tells the figures (what ever they are) to draw and is backend agnostic, where as setting up the toolbar is very backend dependent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable the tool bar via `rcParams`.  Either add (or uncomment) the line

```
toolbar: None
```

in your `matplotlibrc` file or dynamically,

```
rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
```